# ResolvePackageNotFound happens while trying to create an env from yml file

Tags: conda

I am using conda 23.9.0 from Mac (chip: Apple M1 Max, platform: macOS-12.6-arm64-arm-64bit).

When I try to create an env from an yml file, I get ResolvePackageNotFound error.
Command used:
conda env create --file=binder/environment.yml

Outcome:
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed

ResolvePackageNotFound:

- pip==19.0.3=py36_0
- mashtree=0.30
- pytest==3.1.3
- sra-tools==2.9.1_1
- minimap2==2.16
- pysam==0.15.2
- python==3.6.5=1
- lighter==1.1.2
- khmer==3.0.0a2
- sourmash==2.0.0
- groot==0.8.4
  Your kind suggestion to resolve this error will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: See duplicate. This environment can only be run in emulation-mode on **osx-arm64** because: 1) Python 3.6 is unsupported 2) Bioconda channel, which is where `minimap2` etc come from do not build for **osx-arm64**.